# Why is that in some companies being above-average efficient is considered "out of place" or weird?

Tags: work-environment, skills, networking

I just started working for a big, international company that has branches in every state. I am in the Italian one. It's my first job after leaving school.

In the past months my job consisted of consulting on behalf of my main company in another equally huge company (can't really mention names as it would break some confidentiality agreement).

Let's call my main company **A** and my client company **B**.

What I noticed in the work environment of company B is that when you do something that is not common, but makes you more effective in your work, this is seen as "weird" and "out of place", and I have the feeling that they want me to respect their methods, even if my is way more efficient in producing results.

---

A specific example of what happened:

As part of my job I have to constantly check an internal website which is really just a front-end for accessing a database containing information. To get this information you have to make a simple, text-based query with what you are looking for (just like Google).

Now, when you have 1 or 2 things to search, no big deal, you just go to the website, log-in, enter your keyword, wait for the result to appear and copy/paste the result for future use.

Caveats:

- The website has an insanely small session time, so you have to login every second.
- If you have 100 queries to perform, you have to: copy the keyword to clipboard or write it directly -> paste it into the form -> click search -> wait for the answer -> copy/paste it in Excel or whatever -> repeat 99x times.
- No text export, so you have to copy the text to Notepad because otherwise you catch it with the link if you paste it in Word/Excel/etc

Now, since I do not like to do repetitive things which can be somewhat automated, I used my background in programming (currently I am in the networking field / data center side) and made a Python scraper which takes my written query or a text file full of words to search -> logs to the website -> does the query and caches the result for future use + prints it on the screen of my terminal + adds it to a file for export.

So, if I have to do 100 queries, **I am 95% faster than any of my colleagues**.

When my boss in company B found out, he remained astonished and asked why I was doing it, was it really necessary for my work, and in general he gave the impression of not approving it, but without saying it out loud.

In the past weeks, since my time in company B is at the end (they hired me for X days) I am coaching someone else to teach what I do, and this person reported to my boss in company B that *"he does strange things with the computer"* and *"he programs and I don't know how to do it! Is this required for the job?"*.

The boss in company B came to me saying what this person told him, saying that he would prefer me to only use standard, *"everybody-knows-to-do-it"*, tools.

---

**My question here is**: Is it correct for him to ask me to "fly low", even if my additional skills (not required for the job) let me be more efficient?

Comment: When you were coaching the person in your example were you using your programming/tools as part of the task you were training them for?

Comment: No, I did not. At first I showed the "normal" tools. Then, while we were talking about something else work-related I pulled out my script to do a quick search and only *then* this person saw it...

Comment: No one can fault you to automate tasks like this and using it solve some problem. But when it comes to giving this package solution to others the statement from manager B is key: `he would prefer me using only standard, "everybody-knows-to-do-it", tools`. Maybe you have an awesome solution that actually adds value. The problem has nothing to do with laying people off as was suggested in another answer/comment. The constraint has to do with support and risk. Suppose you develop a small automation tool for them. Great but when you're gone no one else knows how to maintain it.

Comment: @Brandin that's actually a nice point of  view! Why not develop it in an answer?

Comment: Just as aside, Word and Excel have both have options to paste in plain, unformatted text for over 10 years. Are you using Office 1997?

Comment: @AmyBlankenship problem is, you have to click that option every damn time when you paste...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's dangerous to be right when everyone around you is wrong.

Let's look at it from their perspective.  With this simple script you have...

- Eliminated 95% of the work.  That's great! Except...
- They may have to lay people off.  A smaller team means less prestige.
- They may charge the client per hour / person. You've just cost the company some serious money.
- Other employees get nervous that they'll be fired because they can't understand what the new kid is doing.
- What happens when your script fails?  Are the session times short for a reason? Will your script break something?
- You're off on holiday and the script does something odd - who can fix it?

In general, you are right to try new things and find ways to be efficient.  But you also have to consider the human cost as well.  You've just made your boss look stupid.  He's been employing all these people and telling *his* boss how great the team is.  Now a teenager has come in and said "you're all idiots, this can be done in 5 minutes using stuff that was invented after you got out of university."

So, how should you approach this?

Start by explaining to your boss what you're doing and why you're doing it.  There may be very good reasons to do it the old way (the law may require an audit trail, for example).

Show your boss the benefits.  Don't say "we have more time" - do say "we've saved money and can pay more attention to XYZ."

Finally - your boss may not be interested in doing things better.  Some people just like working the same way they've always done.

In this case, you can either subvert your boss and try to convince other people yours is the best way - or you can speak to the client directly and ask what they want to do.

Comment: It sounds like it's the client from company B that has the problem, not his boss at company A. If anything he should be *saving* them money.

Comment: "•Eliminated 95% of the work. That's great! Except...
•They may have to lay people off. A smaller team means less prestige."
I won't use company names, but I did this exact thing and they didn't just lay people off, they laid people off based on seniority... I was the newest person on the team... Still pretty bitter about that one to be honest.

Comment: Another problem: If they used an inefficient method for ten years and you easily improve it, that proves they were stupid in the last ten years. Can you imagine why they wouldn't like that? Handling a brand new task efficiently, which was never done inefficiently, that may be much more appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Never do this at any large company without approval. They don't know what your program does and thus they could be worried that it may do more than what you are telling them it does. There are security reasons why you never use unauthorized software on someone else's network.

It is fine to be innovative, but there is a time and a place and you need prior approval. The larger the company the more prior approval is a requrement. What you can do at a startup is vastly differnt than what is allowed at General Motors for instance. That is because the risk of something going wrong is consequently greater. Suppose your little program had a bug and it put things into an infinite loop (I am presuming you didn't have a dev environment to test on). You could have shut down everyone in the office with a mistake on your part. I have seen that happen before. The person who did it got fired too.

Comment: Even worse than preventing others from working, I've seen mistakes like programs dealing with data entry that wind up running an update over an entire table or deleting all records in a table. Not saying you will do this, but you're working outside their comfort zone... you have to take baby steps with this sort of thing, or find someone who's been around longer to side with you to help them feel more like you're doing them a service and less like a loose cannon.

Answer (score 2):

Terence has made some very good points and suggestions.

In addition to this you have to consider that you are a temporary addition to the workforce and that the manager's priorities are therefore going to be with the more permanent people. It seems that your use of your skills has caused some confusion for the person that you were coaching and they are probably trying to prevent further confusion and unrest. The fact that the manager doesn't seem to fully understand your reason for doing this does not help. (The phrase "People are afraid of what they don't understand" comes to mind here).

His response is possibly correct in this regard but the situation could have been handled better, for example asking if there was a way this time saving tool could be used by other people working there.

I would advise you to stop using your custom tools for the rest of your stay or until you've managed to resolve this conflict with the manager.